# Protractor if else only one case can run always

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

so basically i am e2e testing a web site and I am creating a language on the page as the page admin, so in case i something fails or similar my .then() function doesn't work in other words it only works if the code is run and doesn't fail so if it does it doesn't execute the else or the if, in this case if the language is not deleted it will just throw a F and wont execute "Error language not created", and take a screenshot. I am using this method like 20 more times in my script so any help would help on how to improve it if it is possible and to tell me if I am doing something wrong.

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in languages')).
  get(0).isPresent().then(function (result){
                console.log('Deleting language...');
                if(result)
            {

                console.log('Error language not deleted...');
                sShot = true; //Don't mind this, it is for whether to take a screenshot afterEach() or not.

                console.log('-----------------------');
                console.log("\n");
            }

            else{
            console.log('Language deleted!');
            console.log('-----------------------');
            console.log("\n");

            }

            });
```

So if the language isn't deleted which i do above the code i posted when it fails there while deleting it it never executes the isPresent().then() it only executes it when It is successfu. It completely leaves the current test case and goes to the next. l hope I am making sense

Comment: Hi! It's hard to understand what you are actually having problems with. Could you isolate the problem for us more?

Comment: I will edit the code now with my problem